# Frame rate is too slow while displaying frame(RGB data) using OPENGL in android ndk

Tags: android, opengl-es, android-ndk

I am using OpenGL ES in JNI to draw the frame (RGB data) returned from the C source code (MPEG2 Codec). For this I have created one texture and draw RGB data using `glTexSubImage2D()` function of OpenGL. But Using this function I am not getting even 7 FPS. While As I have studied that using OpenGL we can get 22 FPS.

Is there any other specific function to display an image through `android-ndk` which will give better performance than that function (`glTexSubImage2D()`).
I have referred to this [link](http://quirkygba.blogspot.in/2010/10/android-native-coding-in-c.html) to draw frame returned from codec.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The referenced article states that drawing the pixels directly into a bitmap is faster - have you tried it? Are you targeting systems with an OS version < 2.2?

Comment: @BitBank thanks for response.. Yes I am drawing the image by using the code given to the reference link.. And OS version is 3.0. As you are saying it is faster, but I am getting low frame rate...Please tell me solution for this.. I want frame rate around 20fps..

Comment: I've used the method of writing directly into a bitmap and then using canvas.drawBitmap. I usually get > 60fps. On budget phones such as the G1, I would get > 30fps.

Comment: @BitBank Thank u once again for your response.. I have MPEG2 Codec in C language.. Earliar I was sending frame from C to android and using canvas.drawBitmap() to draw the image.. But this process was too slow as It was requiring callbacking from JNI. So I have to switch for OpenGL to avoid callbacking.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by callbacking. Create the bitmap in Java, pass it to C code through JNI. Use bitmap functions to get a pointer to the bits, set the bits and then paint it in your Java code. Quick and efficient.

Comment: @BitBank callbacking means calling android function from JNI. i am not able to know how I can get pointer to bits.Can you please give me some code or any link regarding what you said so that I'll be able to solve the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a set of native bitmap functions added in Android 2.2 which allow you to get direct access to the bits of a bitmap without making a copy of it. In your C code you will use:

```
#include <android/bitmap.h>

JNIEXPORT jint JNICALL Java_com_somecompany_someapp_someclass_drawonbitmap(JNIEnv *env, jobject obj, jobject bitmap)
{
int iReturn;
AndroidBitmapInfo info;
void *pixels;

   iReturn = AndroidBitmap_getInfo(env, bitmap, &info);
   if (iReturn < 0)
   {
       return <some error>;
   }
   iReturn = AndroidBitmap_lockPixels(env, bitmap, &pixels);
   if (iReturn < 0)
   {
       return <some error>;
   }

   // Draw directly into the bitmap here
   //
   // use the structure members:
   // info.stride
   // info.width
   // info.height
   // info.format (e.g. ANDROID_BITMAP_FORMAT_RGB_565)

   if (pixels != NULL) // we previously locked the pixels
   {
       AndroidBitmap_unlockPixels(env, bitmap);
   }
   return 0;
}
```